# Returning Large String from PL/SQL Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

This is a PL/SQL function, and the problem that I encounter with it is that, when it returns a large string, it generates the following message:

> SELECT TODAS_NOTIFICACIONES_ACTIVAS('21/10/2023', 0, 10) as result
> FROM DUAL Error on command line: 1 Column: 8 Error Report - SQL Error:
> ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long ORA-06512: at
> "NOTIFICACIONES_PKG", line 95
>
> 00000 - "result of string concatenation is too long"
> *Cause: String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
> *Action: Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size

this is the function code:

```
FUNCTION TODAS_NOTIFICACIONES_ACTIVAS(fecha_val IN VARCHAR2, start_position IN NUMBER, end_position IN NUMBER)
RETURN CLOB
AS
    l_result1 CLOB;
    l_result2 CLOB;
    l_result3 CLOB;

    l_count NUMBER;
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count
    FROM NOTIFICATIONS
    WHERE TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM
      AND TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO;

    l_result1 := '{ "count": ' || TO_CHAR(l_count) || ', "data": ';

    SELECT '[' ||
           LISTAGG(
               '{ "ID": "' || ID || '", "RECIPIENTS": "' || RECIPIENTS || '", "AGE_FROM": "' || AGE_FROM || '", "AGE_TO": "' || AGE_TO || '", "DEPARTMENT": "' || DEPARTMENT_ID || '", "LOCALITY": "' || LOCALITY_ID || '", "MESSAGE_TITLE": "' || MESSAGE_TITLE || '", "MESSAGE_BODY": "' || MESSAGE_BODY || '", "MULTIMEDIA_ID": "' || MULTIMEDIA_ID || '", "NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM": "' || TO_CHAR(NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '", "NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO": "' || TO_CHAR(NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '", "SEND_BY_EMAIL": "' || SEND_BY_EMAIL || '", "CREATED_AT": "' || TO_CHAR(CREATED_AT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '", "DELETED_AT": "' || TO_CHAR(DELETED_AT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '"}',
               ', '
           ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC) ||
           ']' INTO l_result2
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ID, RECIPIENTS, AGE_FROM, AGE_TO, DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCALITY_ID, 
            MESSAGE_TITLE, MESSAGE_BODY, MULTIMEDIA_ID, 
            NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM, NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO, SEND_BY_EMAIL, 
            CREATED_AT, DELETED_AT,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC) AS rn
        FROM NOTIFICATIONS
        WHERE TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM
          AND TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO
    )
    WHERE rn BETWEEN start_position AND end_position;

    
    l_result3 := l_result1 ||l_result2 || '}';

    RETURN l_result3;
END;
```

Trying to fix it I tried a 'pagination' method using a start_position and an end_position, but I don't know which column number doesn't return that error.For example with 10 rows it was working fine until the error came up for a new notification message. Is there another way to fix it? Any considerations to keep in mind or an initial check to perform before the return?

Comment: Perhaps you should generate the individual rows and combine them in your calling language, and not do the concatenation here.

Comment: Don't use LISTAGG to tabularize data like this. Return normal rows and display the data in the format you want using front-end formatting instructions. The database should just be for storing and retrieving data.

Comment: PL/SQL has a limit of 32K for any string, including CLOBs processed as variables.

Comment: Thanks. @pmdba Where is the documentation to see the limit of 32K. I don't see any documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create JSON in Oracle then, from Oracle 12, use JSON functions and do not try to hand-craft JSON strings (for starters it is failing when the strings get too long but you are also not handling any escape characters that may appear in the strings).

Something like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION TODAS_NOTIFICACIONES_ACTIVAS(
  fecha_val IN VARCHAR2,
  start_position IN NUMBER,
  end_position IN NUMBER
) RETURN CLOB
AS
    l_json CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'count' VALUE COUNT(*),
             KEY 'data' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
               JSON_OBJECT(
                 KEY 'ID' VALUE id,
                 KEY 'RECIPIENTS' VALUE recipients,
                 KEY 'AGE_FROM' VALUE age_from,
                 KEY 'AGE_TO' VALUE age_to,
                 KEY 'DEPARTMENT' VALUE department_id,
                 KEY 'LOCALITY' VALUE locality_id,
                 KEY 'MESSAGE_TITLE' VALUE message_title,
                 KEY 'MESSAGE_BODY' VALUE message_body,
                 KEY 'MULTIMEDIA_ID' VALUE multimedia_id,
                 KEY 'NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM' VALUE TO_CHAR(notification_date_from, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                 KEY 'NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO' VALUE TO_CHAR(notification_date_to, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                 KEY 'SEND_BY_EMAIL' VALUE send_by_email,
                 KEY 'CREATED_AT' VALUE TO_CHAR(created_at, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
                 KEY 'DELETED_AT' VALUE TO_CHAR(deleted_at, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                 RETURNING CLOB
               )
               RETURNING CLOB
             )
             RETURNING CLOB
           )
    INTO   l_json
    FROM   NOTIFICATIONS
    WHERE  TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM
    AND    TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO;

    RETURN l_json;
END;
/
```

*(Re-apply the pagination if you require it.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE notifications (
  id VARCHAR2(20),
  recipients VARCHAR2(20),
  age_from NUMBER,
  age_to NUMBER,
  department_id VARCHAR2(20),
  locality_id VARCHAR2(20),
  message_title VARCHAR2(20),
  message_body VARCHAR2(4000),
  multimedia_id VARCHAR2(20),
  notification_date_from DATE,
  notification_date_to DATE,
  send_by_email VARCHAR2(20),
  created_at DATE,
  deleted_at DATE
);

INSERT INTO notifications (
  id,
  recipients,
  age_from,
  age_to,
  department_id,
  locality_id,
  message_title,
  message_body,
  multimedia_id,
  notification_date_from,
  notification_date_to,
  send_by_email,
  created_at,
  deleted_at
) VALUES (
  'A',
  'B',
  100,
  200,
  'C',
  'D',
  'Title',
  LPAD('E', 4000, 'E'),
  'F',
  TRUNC(SYSDATE),
  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1,
  'G',
  TRUNC(SYSDATE),
  NULL
)
```

Then:

```
SELECT TODAS_NOTIFICACIONES_ACTIVAS(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 1, 1) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TODAS_NOTIFICACIONES_ACTIVAS(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),1,1) |
| --- |
| {"count":1,"data":[{"ID":"A","RECIPIENTS":"B","AGE_FROM":100,"AGE_TO":200,"DEPARTMENT":"C","LOCALITY":"D","MESSAGE_TITLE":"Title","MESSAGE_BODY":"EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE","MULTIMEDIA_ID":"F","NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM":"22/10/2023 00:00:00","NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO":"23/10/2023 00:00:00","SEND_BY_EMAIL":"G","CREATED_AT":"22/10/2023 00:00:00","DELETED_AT":null}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eBotzHVI)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fix it. I have oracle version 11 so I can not implement JSON_OBJECT

```
FUNCTION TODAS_NOTIFICACIONES_ACTIVAS(fecha_val IN VARCHAR2, start_position IN NUMBER, end_position IN NUMBER)
RETURN CLOB
AS
    l_result1 CLOB;
    l_result2 CLOB := '';  -- Inicializa l_result2 para almacenar registros individuales
    l_result3 CLOB;
    l_result_size NUMBER;
    l_count NUMBER;
    l_row_check NUMBER := 0;
    l_json_record VARCHAR2(4000); -- Para almacenar el registro individual como JSON

    CURSOR c_notifications IS
        SELECT 
            '{ "ID": "' || ID || '", "RECIPIENTS": "' || RECIPIENTS || '", "AGE_FROM": "' || AGE_FROM || '", "AGE_TO": "' || AGE_TO || '", "DEPARTMENT": "' || DEPARTMENT_ID || '", "LOCALITY": "' || LOCALITY_ID || '", "MESSAGE_TITLE": "' || MESSAGE_TITLE || '", "MESSAGE_BODY": "' || MESSAGE_BODY || '", "MULTIMEDIA_ID": "' || MULTIMEDIA_ID || '", "NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM": "' || TO_CHAR(NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '", "NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO": "' || TO_CHAR(NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '", "SEND_BY_EMAIL": "' || SEND_BY_EMAIL || '", "CREATED_AT": "' || TO_CHAR(CREATED_AT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '", "DELETED_AT": "' || TO_CHAR(DELETED_AT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '"}' as json_record
        FROM NOTIFICATIONS
        WHERE TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM
          AND TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO
        ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC;

BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count
    FROM NOTIFICATIONS
    WHERE TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') >= NOTIFICATION_DATE_FROM
      AND TO_DATE(fecha_val, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= NOTIFICATION_DATE_TO;

    FOR r in c_notifications LOOP
        IF l_row_check + 1 >= start_position AND l_row_check + 1 <= end_position THEN
            l_json_record := r.json_record;

            l_result_size := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(l_result1 || l_result2 || l_json_record || '}');

            IF l_result_size > 10000 THEN
                EXIT;
            ELSE
                -- Agregar coma si no es el primer registro
                IF l_row_check != 0 THEN
                    l_result2 := l_result2 || ', ';
                END IF;
                l_result2 := l_result2 || l_json_record;
                l_row_check := l_row_check + 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    l_result1 := '{ "count": ' || TO_CHAR(l_count) ||  ',"rows": ' || TO_CHAR(l_row_check) || ', "data": [';  -- Cambiado para que la data esté entre corchetes

    l_result3 := l_result1 || l_result2 || ']}';

    RETURN l_result3;
END;
```